# How do I ask git, which commits are not on a branch?

Tags: git

I haven't payed enough attention, and been working for a little while on "no branch".

The problem is that my works spans weeks of time, and perhaps 10 commits, so it's now obvious to me what exactly has been commited to the right branch, and what has not.

How do I ask git for all the commits that I've created that don't belong in any branch?
And can I merge them all in easily, or do I need to do one merge per commit?

Answer (score 1):

If you are still where you made your last commit you can simply create a new branch with

```
$ git branch new-branch
```

If you don’t have any modified files in your working directory you can now switch to that branch you just created:

```
$ git checkout new-branch
```

Now you can continue as usual, moving commits around using `git cherry-pick` or `git rebase`.

Comment: Then you need to find the commit ID of the last commit you made outside of any branch. `git reflog` could help you there.

Comment: Are you saying that checking out the last commit and branching from there will be the equivalent of manually merging all "lost" commits into a branch? Please update the answer if so :)

Comment: If you manage to find the latest commit and turn it into its own branch (by using `git-branch` as outlined above) they are on their branch which you can then merge into your `master` branch (or wherever you want them). Nothing will be lost.